# How to make mu ordered list correctly?

Tags: html, css

```css
.book-summary ol {
  counter-reset: item ;
}

.book-summary ol li {
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:5px; 
  display:block;
}

.book-summary ol li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item; 
}
```

```html
<div class="book-summary">
       
        <ol>
          <li>Component Location</li>
          <li>Special Tools</li>
          <li>Specifications
            <ol>
              <li>General Inforamation</li>
              <li>Engine</li>
              <li>CVT</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li>Torque Specifications</li>
          <li>Troubleshooting</li>

          <li>cfs</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
```

I want to make a ordered list like a table of contents for a book.
However, there is something wrong with my code that my first level list item only have number("1") not ("1.")

What can I do to have a dot after my first level list item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to makes the first level contains `.` and the next level without `.`, you can use nested selector. Example:

```css
.book-summary ol {
  counter-reset: item ;
}

.book-summary ol li {
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:5px; 
  display:block;
}
.book-summary ol li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item; 
}
.book-summary > ol > li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". "; counter-increment: item; 
}
```

```html
<div class="book-summary">
       
        <ol>
          <li>Component Location</li>
          <li>Special Tools</li>
          <li>Specifications
            <ol>
              <li>General Inforamation</li>
              <li>Engine</li>
              <li>CVT</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li>Torque Specifications</li>
          <li>Troubleshooting</li>

          <li>cfs</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
```

Comment: But the second level will have two dot after each number